# change gasLimit parameter into the genesis.json file on azure priavte blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, gas-limit, microsoft-azure

I am trying to deploy a smart contract to an azure blockchain. The contract is deployed without errors but i can't submit transaction to the blockchain through this contract. I guess this is an issue with gasLimit, because when I use my private geth blockhain where I can set my gasLimit in the genesis.json file, my Dapp works perfectly and I can run my transaction. The gasLimit on azure is set up by microsoft on the genesis.json file and I would like to find a way to change it. How can I do this?

Comment: Any luck? I am interested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you ssh into the azure machine with the "SSH-TO-FIRST-TX-NODE" text on the azure blockchain resource:

```
geth attach
eth.getBlock("pending").gasLimit
```

My default is 4712388.

My working truffle.js file is:

```
module.exports = {
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
// to customize your Truffle configuration!
networks: {
    rpc: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "*"
    },
    "live": {
        host: "<ETHEREUM-RPC-ENDPOINT without the http:// and port number>",
        port: 8545,
        network_id: "1",
        gas: 4612388 // default: 4712388
    }
}
```

};